# What's a best approach to create a filestore

Tags: sql, linux, database

This is an open ended question. I have noob understanding of databases but willing to learn whatever is required. Though I believe my problem could be done without learning a lot.

So, here goes the question: 
I have large amount of files getting generated in mt projects(depending on the builds) and I need to archive them and also need to reproduce them according to buildNumber if requested by users. I don't expect these requests to be a lot. May be 1-2 requests a day.

For eg: 16GB data per build every week. Most of the files in weekly builds are duplicate. And I don't want to archive them again and again. I prefer to store them only once. There is one caveat that it can happen that the files relative location can change, even though content hasn't changed.

My approach is as follow: Create a hash from each file. Create the key-value pair as fileHash-actual file and store it. Store this information in some kind of manifest file for each build. So, I should be able to create the builds back with correct files/paths etc.

Can it ever happen that 2 different files will ever have the same hash? Can some database help to do it efficiently? I am currently thinking of dumping all files in one folder.

Thanks